# How do I achieve multiline popover with bootstrap 3 and angularjs 1.2+?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

What is the cleanest way to achieve multi-line text in a popover with bootstrap 3 and angularjs 1.2+ while using the popover directive https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the option html: true when you initialize the popover. Then 
 and other html tags should work:

```
$(".foo").hover(function () {
    $(this).popover({
        title: "Bar",
        content: "Line 1 <br /> Line 2 <br /> Line 3",
        html: true
    }).popover('show');
}, function () {
    $(this).popover('hide');
});
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/twitter-bootstrap/bhtpERLYCo4

Comment: This is definitely not the cleanest way when using angularjs. I should have clarified I'm using the angularjs directives created for bootstrap 3, though.